# Form calling another form, just to confirm user wants to proceed

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I'm using C# in a VS2008 environment.

I have a form called frmStrategy5YrPlan That has a data grid view in it that populates with data and then allows users to key in new forecast data.  When finished, the users will click a button to upload the new data they've entered, I want another form to display asking them to confirm they want to do this (since the process deletes all of the old data and replaces with what the've entered).

I'm always tricked by forms, but essentially I want my initial form to load the second form, assess whether the user has chosen to confirm loading data (or not) and then process the data using code in the initial form.

here's my initial form, that works fine today without calling the second form (that I'm asking about).  Below it are the beginniner's workings of the code of the 2nd form and the buttons I've added, just trying to get the 2 forms to talk to each other.  It always confuses me when calling a form in another section.  I;m not too familiar with MDIParents but I tried it here and my initial form is not setup as one so I'm not sure if that's the solution.

```
public void btnUploadNewStrategy5YrPlan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this.ConfirmForm.Text = "DSC_0 Staged";
            //this.ConfirmForm.EnableReport(false);
            //this.ConfirmForm.Type = frmConfirmForecastUpload.LoadType.DSC_0;
            //this.ConfirmForm.MdiParent = this;
            this.ConfirmForm.Top = this.Height / 3 - this.ConfirmForm.Height / 2;
            this.ConfirmForm.Left = this.Width / 2 - this.ConfirmForm.Width / 2;
            this.ConfirmForm.Show();
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                var dtForecast = new DataTable();
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Unit");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Year");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Period");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Acct");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Descr");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("DEFERRAL_TYPE");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("NDC_Indicator");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Mgmt Cd");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Prod");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Node");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Curve_Family");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Sum Amount");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Base Curr");
                dtForecast.Columns.Add("Ledger");

                for (int ii = 0; ii < grd1.Rows.Count; ii++)
                {
                    int myCountryKey = int.Parse(grd1.Rows[ii].Cells["colCountryKey"].FormattedValue.ToString());
                    int myCurrencyKey = int.Parse(grd1.Rows[ii].Cells["colCurrencyKey"].FormattedValue.ToString());
                    string myCurrencyCode = grd1.Rows[ii].Cells["colCurr"].FormattedValue.ToString();
                    int myDeferralTypeKey = int.Parse(grd1.Rows[ii].Cells["colDeferralTypeKey"].FormattedValue.ToString());
                    string myDeferralTypeCode = grd1.Rows[ii].Cells["colDeferralType"].FormattedValue.ToString();
                    long myAccount = 6018110000;
                    string myAcctDesc = "";
                    string myCurveFamily = "AH_DM"; //hard coded to AH_DM for now since only DM is in AMORT
                    myDataRegionKey = int.Parse(grd1.Rows[ii].Cells["colRegionKey"].FormattedValue.ToString());
                    myNodeKey = int.Parse(grd1.Rows[ii].Cells["colNodeKey"].FormattedValue.ToString());
                    string myNodeCode = grd1.Rows[ii].Cells["colNodeCode"].FormattedValue.ToString();
                    mySubNodeKeyString = grd1.Rows[ii].Cells["colSubNodeKey"].FormattedValue.ToString();

                    int mySubNodeKey = int.TryParse(mySubNodeKeyString, out mySubNodeKey) ? mySubNodeKey : 0;


                    //Run query to get BU/MCC defaults for this countryKey
                    cmd = util.SqlConn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "proc_get_country_defaults";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@node_key", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myNodeKey;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@country_key", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myCountryKey;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@division_key", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myDivisionKey;
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    dr.Read();
                    int myMCC = (int.Parse(dr["management_code"].ToString()));
                    int myBusinessUnit = (int.Parse(dr["business_unit_code"].ToString()));
                    dr.Close();

                    //Run query to get product defaults for this NodeKey
                    cmd = util.SqlConn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "proc_get_node_defaults";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@node_key", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myNodeKey;
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    dr.Read();
                    int myProductKey = (int.Parse(dr["product_key"].ToString()));                    
                    dr.Close();

                    //Run query to get product defaults for this SubNodeKey
                    cmd = util.SqlConn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "proc_get_sub_node_defaults";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sub_node_key", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mySubNodeKey;
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    //Only overwrite the product key with subnode default if
                    //subnodekey is not null and region is Latin America
                    if (mySubNodeKey > 0 && myDataRegionKey == 100001)
                    {
                        dr.Read();
                        myProductKey = (int.Parse(dr["product_key"].ToString()));
                        dr.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr.Close();
                    }          

                    //Loop through the 5 years
                    for (int jj = 1; jj < 6; jj++)
                    {
                        if (myDataYear > myMostRecentActualYear)
                        {

                            string myYearCount = jj.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
                            string myColName = "col" + myYearCount;
                            double mySumAmt = Convert.ToDouble(grd1.Rows[ii].Cells[myColName].Value) * 1000 / 12;  //Convert annual amount to monthly

                            if (mySumAmt != 0)
                            {

                                //Loop through 12 months
                                for (int nn = 1; nn < 13; nn++)
                                {
                                    int myDataYearToWrite = myDataYear - 1 + jj;

                                    DataRow _fcst = dtForecast.NewRow();
                                    _fcst["Unit"] = myBusinessUnit;
                                    _fcst["Year"] = myDataYearToWrite;
                                    _fcst["Period"] = nn;
                                    _fcst["Acct"] = myAccount;
                                    _fcst["Descr"] = myAcctDesc;
                                    _fcst["DEFERRAL_TYPE"] = myDeferralTypeCode;
                                    _fcst["NDC_Indicator"] = "";
                                    _fcst["Mgmt Cd"] = myMCC;
                                    _fcst["Prod"] = myProductKey;
                                    _fcst["Node"] = myNodeCode;
                                    _fcst["Curve_Family"] = myCurveFamily;
                                    _fcst["Sum Amount"] = mySumAmt;
                                    _fcst["Base Curr"] = myCurrencyCode;
                                    _fcst["Ledger"] = "CORE";

                                    dtForecast.Rows.Add(_fcst);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }                                     

                }

                //Export data table to Excel file
                Excel.Application xlApp;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;

                //// storing header part in Excel 
                for (int q = 1; q < dtForecast.Columns.Count + 1; q++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, q] = dtForecast.Columns[q - 1].ToString().ToUpper() + "\t";
                    string myHeader = dtForecast.Columns[q - 1].ToString().ToUpper();
                }

                // storing grid data part in Excel 
                for (x = 0; x <= dtForecast.Rows.Count - 1; x++)
                {
                    for (y = 0; y <= dtForecast.Columns.Count - 1; y++)
                    {
                        string myData = Convert.ToString(dtForecast.Rows[x][y]);

                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[x + 2, y + 1] = myData;
                    }
                }

                string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();  //System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //+ extension;
                myFileSave = tempPath + fileName;

                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(myFileSave, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);

                xlApp.Quit();

                //Kill Excel objects
                releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                releaseObject(xlApp);

                //MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\AMORT_data.xls");

                //This will import forecast to the zstbl_sol_cost staging table, and validate the data
                ImportStrategy5YrPlan();
                //This will load the data into tbl_cohort and then call Amortizer
                LoadStrategy5YrPlan();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                util.LogError(ex);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (dr != null) dr.Dispose();
                if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
            }


            //dtForecast.Load.Add(theRow);
        }
```

**NEW FORM**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AmortClient
{
    public partial class frmConfirmForecastUpload : Form
    {
        public frmConfirmForecastUpload()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmStrategy5YrPlan console = (frmStrategy5YrPlan)this.MdiParent;
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use a message box and have prompt buttons on it and watch for success.

```
MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Comment: Spectacular.  I was truly making it more difficult than need ( a saying likely to be written on my grave lol.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is a great way to do it, but if for whatever reason you are maybe showing some additonal information and need more than a message box you use the Form.ShowDialog 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog(v=VS.71).aspx

I'm at work so don't have VS to show you a working example atm but just search for a tutorial if you need but basically.

from the first form when you need to open second form you do

if(form2.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK)
{

}